# JavaFX Right Coordinate of a CustomMenuItem

Tags: javafx, custom-controls, coordinates

I have a Class that extends the CustomMenuItem. This MenuItems are added to a ContextMenu. Now i need to get the X-Coordinates from the right side of the CustomMenuItem.

The Problem is, that I have no idea how I can get the Coordinates.
The CustMenuItem has no function for getting the Coordinates like getX() or getY().

So how can I solve this problem?

This thing I would like to get:

[image]

Here we can see a Sample for a Context Menu (red lines). In the Context Menu are a lot of different CustomMenuItems implemented. Now I would like to get the right top corner Coordinate of the CustomMenuItem.

Thank you for your very nice help.

Comment: I've edited my previous answer. Have a look again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before dealing with menu items, let's start saying that a `ContextMenu` is a popup window, so it has `Window`properties. You can ask for (x,y) left, top origin, and for (w,h).

But you have to take into account the effects, since by default it includes a dropshadow. And when it does, there's an extra space added of 24x24 pixels to the right and bottom.

```
.context-menu {
    -fx-effect: dropshadow( gaussian , rgba(0,0,0,0.2) , 12, 0.0 , 0 , 8 );
}
```

Since this default dropshadow has a radius of 12px, and Y-offset to the bottom of 8px, the right and bottom coordinates of the context menu, including the 24x24 area, are given by:

```
X=t.getX()+cm.getWidth()-12-24;
Y=t.getY()+cm.getHeight()-(12-8)-24;
```

where `t` could be a `MouseEvent` relative to the scene, and values are hardcoded for simplicity.

Let's see this over an example. Since you don't say how your custom menu items are implemented, I'll just create a simple Menu Item with graphic and text:

```
private final Label labX = new Label("X: ");
private final Label labY = new Label("Y: ");

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    final ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
    MenuItem cmItem1 = createMenuItem("mNext", "Next Long Option",t->System.out.println("next"));
    MenuItem cmItem2 = createMenuItem("mBack", "Go Back", t->System.out.println("back"));

    SeparatorMenuItem sm = new SeparatorMenuItem();
    cm.getItems().addAll(cmItem1,cmItem2);

    VBox root = new VBox(10,labX,labY);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
    scene.setOnMouseClicked(t->{
        if(t.getButton()==MouseButton.SECONDARY || t.isControlDown()){ 
            // t.getX,Y->scene based coordinates
            cm.show(scene.getWindow(),t.getX()+scene.getWindow().getX()+scene.getX(), 
                                      t.getY()+scene.getWindow().getY()+scene.getY());
            labX.setText("Right X: "+(t.getX()+cm.getWidth()-12-24));
            labY.setText("Bottom Y: "+(t.getY()+cm.getHeight()-4-24));
        }
    });
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("root.css").toExternalForm());
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    primaryStage.setTitle("Scene: "+scene.getWidth()+"x"+scene.getHeight());
}

private MenuItem createMenuItem(String symbol, String text, EventHandler<ActionEvent> t){
    MenuItem m=new MenuItem(text);
    StackPane g=new StackPane();
    g.setPrefSize(24, 24);
    g.setId(symbol);
    m.setGraphic(g);
    m.setOnAction(t);
    return m;
}
```

[image: Custom context menu with effect]

If you remove the effect:

```
.context-menu {
    -fx-effect: null;
}
```

then these coordinates are:

```
X=t.getX()+cm.getWidth();
Y=t.getY()+cm.getHeight();
```

Now that we have the window, let's go into the items.

`MenuItem` skin is derived from a (private) `ContextMenuContent.MenuItemContainer` class, which is a `Region` where the graphic and text are layed out.

When the context menu is built, all the items are wrapped in a `VBox`, and all are equally resized, as you can see if you set the border for the item:

```
.menu-item {
    -fx-border-color: black;
    -fx-border-width: 1;
}
```

This is how it looks like:

[image: Custom context menu with borde]

So the X coordinates of every item on the custom context menu are the same `X` from their parent (see above, with or without effect), minus 1 pixel of padding (by default).

Note that you could also go via private methods to get dimensions for the items:

```
ContextMenuContent cmc= (ContextMenuContent)cm.getSkin().getNode();
System.out.println("cmc: "+cmc.getItemsContainer().getBoundsInParent());
```

Though this is not recommended since private API can change in the future.

**EDIT**

By request, this is the same code removing lambdas and css.

```
private final Label labX = new Label("X: ");
private final Label labY = new Label("Y: ");

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    final ContextMenu cm = new ContextMenu();
    MenuItem cmItem1 = createMenuItem("mNext", "Next Long Option",action);
    MenuItem cmItem2 = createMenuItem("mBack", "Go Back", action);
    SeparatorMenuItem sm = new SeparatorMenuItem();
    cm.getItems().addAll(cmItem1,cmItem2);

    VBox root = new VBox(10,labX,labY);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
    scene.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
            if(t.getButton()==MouseButton.SECONDARY || t.isControlDown()){
                // t.getX,Y->scene based coordinates
                cm.show(scene.getWindow(),t.getX()+scene.getWindow().getX()+scene.getX(),
                        t.getY()+scene.getWindow().getY()+scene.getY());
                labX.setText("Right X: "+(t.getX()+cm.getWidth()-12-24));
                labY.setText("Bottom Y: "+(t.getY()+cm.getHeight()-4-24));
            }
        }
    });
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

    primaryStage.setTitle("Scene: "+scene.getWidth()+"x"+scene.getHeight());
}

private MenuItem createMenuItem(String symbol, String text, EventHandler<ActionEvent> t){
    MenuItem m=new MenuItem(text);
    StackPane g=new StackPane();
    g.setPrefSize(24, 24);
    g.setId(symbol);
    SVGPath svg = new SVGPath();
    svg.setContent("M0,5H2L4,8L8,0H10L5,10H3Z");
    m.setGraphic(svg);
    m.setOnAction(t);
    return m;
}

private final EventHandler<ActionEvent> action = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("action");
    }
};
```

Comment: @JosePerada Is it possible to get a example without css and Java 1.8 Functions like lambda expressions...

Comment: How Can I get the Stage when Im in a other Class ?

Comment: How can I get the Y Position of the Mouse?

Comment: Done, check it and let me know. The 'MouseEvent' object `t` gives you the coordinates of the mouse: check `getY()`, `getSceenY()` and `getScreenY()`.